# Regex expression: Starts with either digits/asterisks or a '+' sign, contains a min of 2 digits and ends with digits/asterisks

Tags: regex

The conditions of the regex that I'm trying to figure out are this:

- It starts with either digits/asterisks or a '+' sign and ends with digits/asterisks.
- It always requires always a minimum of 2 digits.

Example valid strings:

```
240*******
+12*
216438827*
*164*8827*
********21
```

I have been a few hours trying to solve it, but I'm stuck at this regex expression `/^\+?[\d*]{2,}$/`, I cannot figure out how to set the 2 min. digits requirement, so I'll really appreciate some help, thanks!

A related screenshot:

[image: example screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\+?(?:\**\d){2,}\**$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LqzI8S/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\+?` - an optional `+`
- `(?:\**\d){2,}` - two or more occurrences of:

  - `\**` - 0+ `*` chars
  - `\d` - a digit
- `\**` - a `*` symbol
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: It seems to work, amazing Wiktor. I'll accept your answer as soon SO lets me.